# Can I enclose a switch block in a switch block?

Tags: c, switch-statement, keil

I'm using Keil C on an 8051 project and I'm getting error C175 - Duplicate Case value from the following:

```
switch (x) 
{
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        switch (y) 
        {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
        }
}
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Why are you `break`ing in all cases? What's the purpose of this weird block? Is this only for the sake of the example?

Comment: Try putting the inner `switch` in a scope block, i.e. surround it with `{}`s.

Comment: Actually I've taken all the code out for simplicity (obviously). I did add:
 If (some test) {
    Switch (y)
    {
        Case ….
    }

And it didn’t make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler is broken. Keil is infamous for its poor standard compliance.

C11 6.8.4.2/3

> The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant
>   expression and no two of the case constant expressions in the same
>   switch statement shall have the same value after conversion. There may
>   be at most one default label in a switch statement. **(Any enclosed
>   switch statement may have a default label or case constant expressions
>   with values that duplicate case constant expressions in the enclosing
>   switch statement.)**

The above bold, normative text is there in any version of the C standard.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a compiler bug. With gcc your code works flawlessly: http://ideone.com/u4svzf. This is the tested code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x, y;
    switch (x) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        switch (y) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
        }
    }
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put "0" and "1" as case statements within another switch which has 0 and 1 for a case.

You can find the explanation [here](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_c175.htm).

[EDİT]: Actually the explanation says "in the same statement" but we understand from here: in keil C we cannot enclose a switch block in a switch block. Like @niklasfi said, it runs perfectly in gcc(I tried too).

Comment: I edited the answer, and you can see the niklasfi's answer is about gcc, but the question is about keil c.

Comment: Sorry.Didn't notice that compiler there